# azure AI QUERY combine start and response to calculate average

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm quite new to azure's application insights analytics query.

I'm trying to make some reports out of the data I have.

In the table `customEvents`, there are rows that represents the start and the return (aka Start & Success) of a request (aka Event), but I cannot figure out how to combine the Start and Success for calculating an average/making a report.

```
let table1 = customEvents | extend Start=timestamp | where customDimensions.Action == "Start" and customDimensions.Event == "A" | project Start, operation_Id;
let table2 = customEvents | extend Success=timestamp | where customDimensions.Action == "Success" and customDimensions.Event == "A" | project Success, operation_Id;

union  table*
```

Disappointingly, I can only get the following result:

```
Start                       Success                 operation_Id
___________________________________________________________________
2016-12-12T07:09:23.466Z    null                        EktA4
2016-12-12T07:09:32.479Z    null                        EktA4
2016-12-12T07:09:37.392Z    null                        EktA4
2016-12-12T09:09:27.645Z    null                        YpgOq
null                        2016-12-12T07:09:26.551Z    EktA4
null                        2016-12-12T07:09:33.848Z    EktA4
null                        2016-12-12T07:09:38.265Z    EktA4
null                        2016-12-12T09:09:29.927Z    YpgOq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join for that, not a union. It took me a while to create joins in Application Insights but try this.

```
let startEvents = customEvents
| where customDimensions.Action == "Start" and customDimensions.Event == "A"    
| extend Start = timestamp 
    | project operation_Id, Start;
customEvents
| where customDimensions.Action == "Succes" and customDimensions.Event == "A"    
    | extend Success = timestamp 
    | join kind=leftouter startEvents on operation_Id
    | project operation_Id, Start, Success
```

**Edit:**

You might run into a problem though. You have multiple starts and success for the same operation. How should those be matched correctly? You should have a unique value that relates to 1 Start/Success combination.

Comment: tx @Peter that gave me results with start and success on one line, and your "Edit" points oud the dilemma in de results , in both cases it joins the first "success" he can find not the closes . i wonder if it is even possible to overcome this in a AIQL

Comment: Maybe you can create an unique value in the customdimensions for each start/success combination. So you can use that one instead of operation_Id?

Comment: that sounds like the best option(not sure yet if the programmer wil/can make that), and i'm still wondering if there is a way with AIQL

Comment: well, it do not think it is a AISQL related problem. If it was, for example, a relation db you still have a problem when there is no unique identifier per start/success combination.